# Easy way to classify words like "A lot", "A few", "some"

Tags: python, nlp

I am working on a project that needs to be able to classify modifiers like "a lot", "a few", "lots", "some" etc. into minimum percentages

For example `"a lot"` -> `80%`

Right now I'm thinking of simply creating a large dictionary that relates these modifiers and numerical values e.g.

`a few` -> `15%`

`some` -> `10%`

`lots` -> `80%`

However this is very laborious and probably won't cover all scenarios. Is there an easier way to do this, or is there a NLP tool that already exists for this purpose - preferably in python (or a database out there already?)

Answer (score 1):

Similarity is actually a difficult problem in NLP. I recommend you to use Word2Vec and generate word embeddings of each word. Then you can compare the distance of each word pair and see if could word better than your way. The key to improve the effectiveness of word embedding is to pick a corpus which is large enough and specifies on the area closer to your problem.

Comment: Do you mean map `"a few"` to `15%` and then look for words similar to `"a few"` such as `"a little"` with Word2Vec?

Comment: I mean you can get the vector of "a few","a little"  by word2vec and see if ti works. Just an idea and you can try.

Comment: That's interesting. I'll give that a shot. Do you know if there is a corpus or data collection for say the 100 most common words like "lots", "few" that relates those to some numerical value? If I had a starting point I could use word2vec from there.